# Issue on Selecting Bootstrap Select 3

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-select

I am trying to load some options to Bootstrap 3 + Bootstrap-Select  from MYSQL database using Ajax, PHP, and jQuery on [my page here](http://appmap.dx.am).

But there are few issues happening here:

1. The selected options are not showing at the box. Instead the `Select From The List` is still there, and if you click to select an option, it is empty and `Nothing Selected` displays on selection box
2. If you click on another btns to load srt of data the *first* click does nothing but the *second* click change update the list as it is supposed to be.

How can I fix this and force the dropdown to change its states with the first click?

Here is the code I used to load data:

```html
<div class="panel panel-default">
  <div class="panel-heading">
    4 - Select Species 
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-xs pull-right" id="specicPop">?</button>
  </div>
  <div class="panel-body">
    <div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons" id="speciesSelect">
      <button id="allspecies" type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm">All Species</button>
      <button id="aquatic" type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm">Aquatic</button>
      <button id="terrestria" type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm">Terrestrial</button>
    </div>
    <select id="arearesults" class="selectpicker" data-live-search="true">
      <option value="select">Select From The List</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
```

```js
$('.btn-group .btn').click(function(){
  //alert( $(this).attr('id') );
  $.post(
    'con/animalList.php',
    //datatype: "html",
    { selType : this.id },
    function(data) {
      $('#arearesults').html(data);
    }
  );
  $('#arearesults').selectpicker("refresh");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try moving the line:

```
$('#arearesults').selectpicker("refresh");
```

after:

```
$('#arearesults').html(data);
```

You are refreshing the selectpicker before the data is loaded.  Moving inside the `function(data){..}` block ensures your data is loaded.